# Can someone please ELI5 how to install the Unity desktop onto my Windows 8.1 install?

Tags: unity, windows-8

As much as I'd love to, I can't use Ubuntu for everything, but I want to at least make Windows look like my favorite OS. I have no idea about the whole software architecture behind Unity/X, so I really need a simple explanation.

Comment: But it's offtopic here, on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Make-Windows-8-1-Look-Like-Ubuntu-13-10-399448.shtml but this is about Windows, so not on topic here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ELI5 version: You can't.

Long version: If you need Windows and need to get your Ubuntu fix, you might want to try [installing Ubuntu in a virtual machine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox) using VirtualBox, or [dual-booting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot). There might be Windows themes/hacks to make it look like Ubuntu, but it won't be the actual Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Attempting to actually compile and install Unity (or, more likely, the old Unity 2D) via Cygwin/X might be another (long shot!) alternative.